# transitive closure python tuples

Tags: python, closures

Does anyone know if there's a python builtin for computing transitive closure of tuples?

I have tuples of the form `(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)` and I'm trying to get `(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(1,3)(2,4)`

Thanks.

Comment: What do mean 'transitive' and 'closure' here ? What is the principle of the appearance of (1,3) and (2,4) ? Are your tuples always the same length ? What does mean 'computing tuples' ?

Comment: More on transitive closure here [transitive_closure](http://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/HTML/transitiveClosure.html). Essentially, the principle is if in the original list of tuples we have two tuples of the form `(a,b)` and `(c,z)`, and `b` equals `c`, then we add tuple `(a,z)`
Tuples will always have two entries since it's a binary relation. By 'computing tuples' I mean extending the original list of tuples to become the transitive closure.

Comment: Thank you. I was totally ignorant of this notion.

Comment: Since it appears (2,4) , should (1,4) appear too from (1,2) and the new (2,4) ?

Comment: If there was something builtin for this, it would be in http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html, but it appears no such thing exists (built-in, that is).

Comment: yes @eyquem, that's exactly right, so a solution must include some form of repetition until the closure is found.

Comment: Do you really need it to be a builtin? [python-graph](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-graph) provides that functionality.

Answer (score 13):

There's no builtin for transitive closures.

They're quite simple to implement though.

Here's my take on it:

```
def transitive_closure(a):
    closure = set(a)
    while True:
        new_relations = set((x,w) for x,y in closure for q,w in closure if q == y)

        closure_until_now = closure | new_relations

        if closure_until_now == closure:
            break

        closure = closure_until_now

    return closure
```

call:
`transitive_closure([(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)])`

result:
`set([(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (3, 4), (2, 4)])`

call:
`transitive_closure([(1,2),(2,1)])`

result:
`set([(1, 2), (1, 1), (2, 1), (2, 2)])`

Comment: +1, very elegant. Never mind my previous comment :) Btw., `new_relations` strictly hold *relationships* in set-theoretic parlance, or *edges* in graph terms.

Comment: we should not have `(2,2)` in the 2nd call's result.

Comment: @Duke yes you should (2,2) = (2,1) * (1,2)

Comment: @Duke: if xRy and yRz, then the transitive closure of R includes (x,z). In this situation, x=z=2 and y=1, so (2,2) should be included.

Comment: Is this the Warshall algorithm?

Comment: For around 10k tupels this takes forever.

Answer (score 4):

Just a quick attempt:

```
def transitive_closure(elements):
    elements = set([(x,y) if x < y else (y,x) for x,y in elements])

    relations = {}
    for x,y in elements:
        if x not in relations:
            relations[x] = []
        relations[x].append(y)

    closure = set()
    def build_closure(n):
        def f(k):
            for y in relations.get(k, []):
                closure.add((n, y))
                f(y)
        f(n)

    for k in relations.keys():
        build_closure(k)

    return closure
```

Executing it, we'll get

```
In [3]: transitive_closure([(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)])
Out[3]: set([(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4)])
```

Comment: maybe `relations` is not the correct name; it just stores, for each number, the other "reachable" numbers, building a DAG. The recursive function `build_closure` creates all the matches visiting the graph (this solution has however strong input assumptions, a more flexible (and complex) may be more suitable for other inputs)
[duh, comment removed.. leaving this answer for reference]

Comment: This will run into infinite recursion if there is a cycle in the input. (I misinterpreted the code the first time, somehow thinking you were iterating over pairs of elements rather than tuple-unpacking individual elements while building `relations`.)

Comment: I'd expect `transitive_closure([(1,2),(2,1)])` to include (as mine does) `(1,1)` and `(2,2)` in the output, but I don't know exactly what OP wants...

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: that's the transitive and reflexive closure.

Comment: you're right karl. i just hit it `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp`

Comment: In the first line, you seem to be reversing the elements of a tuple depending on a comparison, but why?  In other words, transitive_closure([(4,3)]) returns set([(3,4)].

Answer (score 4):

We can perform the "closure" operation from a given "start node" by repeatedly taking a union of "graph edges" from the current "endpoints" until no new endpoints are found. We need to do this at most (number of nodes - 1) times, since this is the maximum length of a path. (Doing things this way avoids getting stuck in infinite recursion if there is a cycle; it will waste iterations in the general case, but avoids the work of checking whether we are done i.e. that no changes were made in a given iteration.)

```
from collections import defaultdict

def transitive_closure(elements):
    edges = defaultdict(set)
    # map from first element of input tuples to "reachable" second elements
    for x, y in elements: edges[x].add(y)

    for _ in range(len(elements) - 1):
        edges = defaultdict(set, (
            (k, v.union(*(edges[i] for i in v)))
            for (k, v) in edges.items()
        ))

    return set((k, i) for (k, v) in edges.items() for i in v)
```

(I actually tested it for once ;) )

Answer (score 2):

Suboptimal, but conceptually simple solution:

```
def transitive_closure(a):
    closure = set()
    for x, _ in a:
        closure |= set((x, y) for y in dfs(x, a))
    return closure

def dfs(x, a):
    """Yields single elements from a in depth-first order, starting from x"""
    for y in [y for w, y in a if w == x]:
        yield y
        for z in dfs(y, a):
            yield z
```

This won't work when there's a cycle in the relation, i.e. a reflexive point.

Comment: it does flop on cycles though.

Comment: @soulcheck: you're right. Documented that; there's plenty of better solutions posted already.

Comment: it's easy to correct, as in typical dfs. once you see a cycle, return the node that creates it and backtrack.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one essentially the same as the one from @soulcheck that works on adjacency lists rather than edge lists:

```
def inplace_transitive_closure(g):
    """g is an adjacency list graph implemented as a dict of sets"""
    done = False
    while not done:
        done = True
        for v0, v1s in g.items():
            old_len = len(v1s)
            for v2s in [g[v1] for v1 in v1s]:
                v1s |= v2s
            done = done and len(v1s) == old_len
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of tupels (more than 5000), you might want to consider using the scipy code for matrix powers (see also http://www.ics.uci.edu/~irani/w15-6B/BoardNotes/MatrixMultiplication.pdf)

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix as csr
def get_closure(tups):
    index2id = list(set([tup[0] for tup in tups]) | set([tup[1] for tup in tups]));
    id2index = {index2id[i]:i for i in xrange(len(index2id))};
    tups_re  = tups + [(index2id[i],index2id[i],) for i in xrange(len(index2id))]; # Unfortunately you have to make the relation reflexive first - you could also add the diagonal to M
    M        = csr( ([True for tup in tups_re],([id2index[tup[0]] for tup in tups_re],[id2index[tup[1]] for tup in tups_re])),shape=(len(index2id),len(index2id)),dtype=bool);
    M_       = M**n; # n is maximum path length of your relation
    temp     = M_.nonzero();
    #TODO: You might want to remove the added reflexivity tupels again
    return [(index2id[temp[0][i]],index2id[temp[1][i]],) for i in xrange(len(temp[0]))];
```

In the best case, you can choose `n` wisely if you know a bit about your relation/graph -- that is how long the longest path can be. Otherwise you have to choose `M.shape[0]`, which might blow up in your face.

This detour also has its limits, in particular you should be sure than the closure does not get too large (the connectivity is not too strong), but you would have the same problem in the python implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a graph from those tuples then use connnected components algorithm from the created graph. [Networkx](http://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected_components.html) is library that supports connnected components algorithm.